# Надо дать указатель переменной в функцию, которая что-то изменит в переменной

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

Пытался сделать указатель на переменную списка, которая предается в функцию, но после функции переменная не меняется.

Вот вывод:
10
0
0

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 class List{
    public:

    List(){ next = NULL; data = 0;}
    int data;
    List* next;
 };

 int pop(List* x){ // delete one from the end and type data ||-||-/  *5*
    return x->data;  // ещё не доделал
 }

 void push (List* root, int value){     // insert line to the end ||-||-|new|
    List *node = new List();
    node->data = value;
    node->next = root;
    root = node;
    cout << root->data << endl;
}

 int main(){
    List root;
    push(&root, 10);
    cout << root.data << endl;
    cout<< pop(&root);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая задача в с++ решается с помощью ссылки на указатель

```
void push(List*& root, int value) {
    List *node = new List();
    node->data = value;
    node->next = root;
    root = node;
    cout << root->data << endl;
}
```

Но нельзя просто передать туда адресс объекта, как это происходит в вашем коде:

`List root; push(&root, 10);`

Раз указатель будет изменятся (в функции `push`), значит передаваемый указатель должен быть lvalue-значением, а операция взятия адресса объекта возвращает временный указатель. Рабочий вариант будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
int main() {
    List object;
    List* root = &object;
    push(root, 10);
    cout << root->data << endl;
    // далее работать с указателем root, а не с object
}
```

Но еще более лучшим решением будет использование одного подхода. Если в `push` новые элементы создаются динамически будет разумно использовать такой подход для всего списка:

```
int main() {
    List* root = new List;
    push(root, 10);
    cout << root->data << endl;
    // ...
}
```

Кроме прочего, вы работаете в стиле процедурного программирования. И не забывайте удалять то, что ранее выделили выражением `new`.

Comment: Как вариант, `List* root = 0;`.